# Historical Trending of a JVM

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring, jmx

Is there a open source tool readily available that would monitor remote JVM processes on a server.

Ideally it would read the telemetry via JMX and store into a historical database with a pretty GUI to present the information

The key information I would like are memory, `gc` times, threads, classes, etc

Comment: extend VisualVM http://visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html to full fill your historical storage need

Answer (score 5):

The JDK supplies two graphical tools to monitor the performances -

- jVisualVM and
- jConsole

They are both located in the bin directory of the JDK.

Unfortunately they both do not allow to programmatically save the snapshots at regular intervals, nor they offer a command line version which can be used for scripting.

A good opensource solution is [jmxmonitor](http://jmxmonitor.sourceforge.net/)

*The JMX Monitor Project provides a daemon (or commandline) tool to monitor a series of JMX services.*

*These are outputted to rolling log files for external tools (e.g. Nagios or Cacti) to process.*

Another option is [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring):

*Zabbix is software that monitors numerous parameters of a network and the health and integrity of servers. Zabbix uses a flexible notification mechanism that allows users to configure e-mail based alerts for virtually any event. This allows a fast reaction to server problems. Zabbix offers excellent reporting and data visualisation features based on the stored data. This makes Zabbix ideal for capacity planning.*

However, if you are interested in "basic data logging" directly to a database, probably writing your own is the best solution - especially if you want to monitor multiple VMs - and it is not terribly difficult, see: [Monitoring a remote VM through the platform server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mxbeans/#8) and [Monitoring and Management Using JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html)

Example:

```
final JMXServiceURL address = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + SERVER_JMXPORT + "/jmxrmi");
final String[] credentials = new String[] { ADMIN, PASSWORD };
final Map<String, String[]> props = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
props.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

final JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(address, props);
final MBeanServerConnection mbs = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

//Show the name and the state of all the threads
final ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(mbs, ManagementFactory.THREAD_MXBEAN_NAME, ThreadMXBean.class);
final long[] threadIDs = threadBean.getAllThreadIds();
final ThreadInfo[] threadDataset = threadBean.getThreadInfo(threadIDs);
for (final ThreadInfo threadData : threadDataset) {
    if (threadData != null) {
        System.out.println(threadData.getThreadName() + " " + threadData.getThreadState());
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Current: " + threadBean.getThreadCount() + " peak " + threadBean.getPeakThreadCount());
```

Once you have the data stored in a database, there are plenty of tools to represent that data in graphical format for analysis.

Comment: Is VisualVM open source tool?

Comment: It has the same licence as Java - http://visualvm.java.net/index.html  http://java.net/projects/visualvm/sources/svn/show

Comment: the key requirement is to store the data, I know I can build something custome for this but I'd rather not

Comment: http://jmxmonitor.sourceforge.net/index.html seems quite basic but probably it is the best you can get for free